# Mockito Mock Entity Manger doesn't work properly

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, junit5

I have provided the sample code below. But when the test runs, it calls the database to fetch data and get data from the database.
Why mocking doesn't work properly? how to avoid database calls in those types of services?

EndPoint: `/v1/reservations/calculate-price-by-id/{reservation_id}`

Service Layer

```java
public Object getPrice(Long reservation_id){
    String stringQuery = "SELECT distinct u FROM Reservation u left join fetch u.driverAssignment  where u.id=:reservation_id";
    Query query = em.createQuery(stringQuery);
    query.setParameter("reservation_id", reservation_id);
    List<Reservation> reservations = query.getResultList();
    if(reservations.size()==0)
        return new DefaultResponseDTO(201, ResponseStatus.INVALID_INPUTS, "Reservation Id Not valid");

    return new DefaultResponseDTO(200, ResponseStatus.OK, "Price Calculated.", reservations );
}
```

Unit Test

```java
@Test
@DisplayName("Get prices of a reservation by it's id")
void getPaymentById() throws Exception {

   List<Reservation> list = new LinkedList<>();
   Query queryByMock =  Mockito.mock(TypedQuery.class);
   String stringQuery = "SELECT distinct u FROM Reservation u left join fetch u.driverAssignment  where u.id=:reservation_id";
   Mockito.when(em.createQuery(stringQuery)).thenReturn(queryByMock);
   Mockito.when(queryByMock.getResultList()).thenReturn(list);

   mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
           .get("/v1/reservations/calculate-price-by-id/1").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
           .andExpect(status().isOk())
           .andExpect(jsonPath("$.code", is(200)))
           .andExpect(jsonPath("$.data",hasSize(3)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are mocking the `createQuery` called with exactly `stringQuery`. You might want to change this and basically accept any String. Try the following:

```java
@Test
@DisplayName("Get prices of a reservation by it's id")
void getPaymentById() throws Exception {

   List<Reservation> list = new LinkedList<>();
   Query queryByMock = Mockito.mock(Query.class);
   String stringQuery = "SELECT distinct u FROM Reservation u left join fetch u.driverAssignment  where u.id=:reservation_id";
   Mockito.when(em.createQuery(anyString())).thenReturn(queryByMock);
   Mockito.when(queryByMock.getResultList()).thenReturn(list);

   mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
           .get("/v1/reservations/calculate-price-by-id/1").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
           .andExpect(status().isOk())
           .andExpect(jsonPath("$.code", is(200)))
           .andExpect(jsonPath("$.data",hasSize(3)));
}
```

Nevertheless, this will only work if you are injecting the `EntityManager` mock `em` in your Service during Unit Test setup. Please make sure you do.

Comment: I tried with `anyString()` but also it didn't work for me. And if there are two query strings in the same method we cannot use `anyString()`. I inject EntityManager as `@MockBean private EntityManager em`.

Comment: Yes, you can't but in your example there are not two Strings, only one. Can you please include the complete test Class so that we can check what else you have there? Is this supposed to be an Integration Test?

Comment: I've edited my answer. I changed the line `Query queryByMock = Mockito.mock(Query.class);`. The reason being that `EntityManager.createQuery(String)` method returns a `Query` not a `TypedQuery`.